# ReactJs failing to bind data object

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to ReactJs and I'm trying to bind a http response to the DOM, but I can't get it to work. Im using componentDidMount to execute the api call. Any help will be much appreciated, please see code below.

```
var testStuff="First State";
var Test = React.createClass({
    loadTestData: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:64443/api/articles/apitest",
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                testStuff= response;
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });

    },
    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadTestData();
    },

    render() {
        console.log(this.testStuff);
        return (
          <div onClick={this.loadTestData}>
        {testStuff}
      </div>
    );
}
});
ReactDOM.render(
  <Test />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

The onClick seems to be working, but its almost like the componentDidMount only gets executed after the page is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly update the component state in the AJAX success handler: `this.setState({ testStuff: data })`

Then you will be able to access it in `render` using `this.state.testStuff`.

`componentDidMount` indeed only runs after component has been mounted. You will also need to represent the UI state where the requests is still ongoing (`this.state.testStuff` will be `undefined` at that point).